# Solving multi equations in matrix form using fsolve (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, equations

Good morning,
I'm trying to solve 8 equations with 8 unknowns using fsolve and want to see how results are changing with one parameter (Vn1). When used it doesn't work correctly - it overwrites score and at the end there is only result with last value of Vn1. Can you help me?

Here is my code:

```
clear
clc

Vn=100;
Vn1=[10;11;12;13];
Vn3=20;
wn=1;
lambda1=0.1;
lambda3=0.2;
R1=0.99;
R3=0.98;

fun1 = @(x) [(Vn-Vn1+x(1)-x(2));
            x(2)-Vn3+x(3)-x(4);
            x(5)-wn.*(1+lambda1.*R1./(1-lambda1));
            x(6)-x(7).*(1+lambda3.*R3./(1-lambda3));
            x(7).*x(2)-wn.*(Vn-Vn1)-x(5.)*x(1);
            x(8).*x(4)-x(7).*(x(2)-Vn3)-x(6).*x(3);
            x(1)-Vn1+lambda1.*Vn1;
            x(3)-Vn3+lambda3.*Vn3];

x0(8,4)=0;
x = fsolve(fun1,x0);
plot(Vn1,x(8))
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You want to solve 4 independent set of equations, each consisting of 8 unknowns and equations. So, `x0` correctly is a `8x4` matrix, but `fun1` should also be an `8x4` matrix. `Vn1` should probably be a row vector (`1x4`) and you should use `x(i, :)` instead of linear indexing `x(i)`.

Comment: It' working. Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe you can post your corrected code as an answer and accept it. It may be useful for others.

Comment: Yes, of course. I was trying to do it as your answer but as I see only I can post it. I wanted to post it as an acknowledgment to you.

Comment: It's nice of you that you want to acknowledge me. You can upvote my comment or refer to my comment in your answer, but the most important thing is that the solution is available to everyone. I included my comment in your answer, I think you can accept it now.

Comment: It's says I can accept my answer in 2 days

Comment: I really hate time limit restrictions.

Comment: I will do it for sure. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by m7913d in his comment, I want to solve 4 independent sets of equations, each consisting of 8 unknowns and 8 equations. So, `x0` correctly is a `8x4` matrix, but `fun1` should also be an `8x4` matrix. Therefore, `Vn1` should be a row vector (`1x4`) and I should use `x(i, :)` instead of linear indexing `x(i)`:

```
clear
clc

Vn=100;
Vn1=linspace(10,50,100);
Vn3=20;
wn=1;

lambda3=0.2;
lambda1=0.1;
R1=0.99;
R3=0.98;
fun1 = @(x) [(Vn-Vn1+x(1,:)-x(2,:));
            x(2,:)-Vn3+x(3,:)-x(4,:);
            x(5,:)-wn.*(1+lambda1.*R1./(1-lambda1));
            x(6,:)-x(7,:).*(1+lambda3.*R3./(1-lambda3));
            x(7,:).*x(2,:)-wn.*(Vn-Vn1)-x(5,:).*x(1,:);
            x(8,:).*x(4,:)-x(7,:).*(x(2,:)-Vn3)-x(6,:).*x(3,:);
            x(1,:)-Vn1+lambda1.*Vn1;
            x(3,:)-Vn3+lambda3.*Vn3];

x0(8,100)=10;
x = fsolve(fun1,x0);
plot(Vn1,x(8,:))
xlabel('Vn1')
ylabel('wr')
```